# How to custom-format the display of numpy array column brackets, in LaTeX for Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, latex, jupyter-notebook, output-formatting

I am studying DL on deeplearning.ai. In this course Andrew stacks training examples in columns like following.

[image]

where numpy actually print array like this.

[image]

My question is, how to customize the output of numpy as follow

[image]

that is, have the inner square brackets 'longer' to cover whole column.

any response would be appreciated.

Thanks to smci's inspiration, I got this.

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
display(Math(r'\begin{align}\quad\boldsymbol X=\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}135 \\30 \\\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}57 \\15 \\\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}150 \\35 \\\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}'))
```

Another question shows up:

The latex notation such as {align} occupy the python format {}, how to solve this? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, you want to customize the display format (e.g. HTML/CSS, LateX), rather than the output (i.e. numerical values). Do you want to display this in a notebook, webpage, export to document?

Comment: Both are great! Thank you! Your question inspired me. I will look for a way to print a LateX with python in jupyter notebook

Comment: Great. If you search on those keywords, you'll probably find a duplicate.

Comment: this one could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422762/is-it-possible-to-show-print-output-as-latex-in-jupyter-notebook

I will give an answer for my own question if is allowed as this is a duplicate

Comment: Sure, that's a direct duplicate. Please post your answer there. We can close this question as duplicate, so it redirects to that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to show \`print\` output as LaTeX in jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422762/is-it-possible-to-show-print-output-as-latex-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small function that uses unicode to display a matrix as columns. How to hook this into Jupyter I don't know:

```
>>> def pretty_col(data):
...     assert data.ndim == 1
...     if data.size <= 1:
...         return format(data)
...     else:
...         return format(data[:, None])[1:-1].replace('[', '\u23A1', 1).replace(' [', '\u23A2', data.size-2).replace(' [', '\u23A3').replace(']', '\u23A4', 1).replace(']', '\u23A5', data.size-2).replace(']', '\u23A6')
...
>>> def pretty_cols(data, comma=False):
...     assert data.ndim == 2
...     if comma:
...         return '\n'.join(line[0] + line + line[-1] for line in map(str.join, data.shape[0] // 2 * ('  ',) + (', ',) + (data.shape[0] - 1) // 2 * ('  ',), zip(*map(str.split, map(pretty_col, data.T), data.shape[1]*('\n',)))))
...     else:
...         return '\n'.join(line[0] + line + line[-1] for line in map(''.join, zip(*map(str.split, map(pretty_col, data.T), data.shape[1]*('\n',)))))

...
>>> print(pretty_cols(np.arange(-1, 2, 0.25).reshape(4, 3)))
⎡⎡-1.  ⎤⎡-0.75⎤⎡-0.5 ⎤⎤
⎢⎢-0.25⎥⎢ 0.  ⎥⎢ 0.25⎥⎥
⎢⎢ 0.5 ⎥⎢ 0.75⎥⎢ 1.  ⎥⎥
⎣⎣ 1.25⎦⎣ 1.5 ⎦⎣ 1.75⎦⎦
>>> 
>>> print(pretty_cols(np.arange(-1, 2, 0.25).reshape(4, 3), True))
⎡⎡-1.  ⎤  ⎡-0.75⎤  ⎡-0.5 ⎤⎤
⎢⎢-0.25⎥  ⎢ 0.  ⎥  ⎢ 0.25⎥⎥
⎢⎢ 0.5 ⎥, ⎢ 0.75⎥, ⎢ 1.  ⎥⎥
⎣⎣ 1.25⎦  ⎣ 1.5 ⎦  ⎣ 1.75⎦⎦
```

Comment: This solution perfectly fulfill my need. Thank you so much!