# How do I display a latex string as latex output in sympy (jupyter notebook)?

Tags: python, sympy

My preamble in Jupyter is:

```
%reset
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator, Dagger, Operator
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)
```

How do I print the following string in latex form? I crucially do not want the order of the terms within the string to change.

```
'\\mathbf{R}_B \\cdot j'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422762/is-it-possible-to-show-print-output-as-latex-in-jupyter-notebook)

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
display(Math('\\mathbf{R}_B \\cdot j'))
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So an answer is:

from IPython.display import Math

```
display(Math('\\mathbf{R}_B \\cdot j'))
```

Which preserves the order of the symbols. However, 'Math' has no attribute 'subs' and has trouble sympifying, so it seems doing sympy operations on this output isn't possible.