# how to write a class which naturally produce a latex output in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

This question is not a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422762/is-it-possible-to-show-print-output-as-latex-in-jupyter-notebook), even if it is closely related.

When I use sympy on a jupyter notebook, it nicely format the output of my equations with MathJax, like this:

[image: sympy latex output demonstration]

If we have a look at the source of the notebook, we can see that the output saved is made of two parts `text/plain` and `text/latex` :

```
"outputs": [
 {
  "data": {
   "text/latex": [
    "$\\displaystyle \\frac{- b - \\sqrt{- 4 a c + b^{2}}}{2 a}$"
   ],
   "text/plain": [
    "(-b - sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)"
   ]
  },
  "execution_count": 22,
  "metadata": {},
  "output_type": "execute_result"
 }
],
"source": [
 "import sympy\n",
 "\n",
 "a, b, c = sympy.symbols('a b c')\n",
 "(-b - sympy.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)"
]
```

Even if I know how to print in a latex form (cf. link above), I would like to make a custom object behave as a sympy one, and be able to be displayed naturally as latex math in a jupyter notebook (and if I could fill both the text/latex and text/plain fields it would be nice !). If anyone had a clue on how to do it :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your specifically want to do. You may want to get more Jupyter people's eyes on it by posting at [the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). Please note here if you end up doing that. It sounded like digging in how sympy works and how MathJax gets made may provide you a route? Maybe looking into how [latexify_py](https://twitter.com/KhuyenTran16/status/1575136709544747008) or [latex2sympy2](https://github.com/OrangeX4/latex2sympy) would help you where you want to go?

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I will ask the jupyter community and update this page if I find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the forum and got a fast answer ([link](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-write-a-class-which-naturally-produce-a-latex-output-in-jupyter-notebook/17437)), as promised, I copy/paste it here (all credits goes to [bollwyvl](https://discourse.jupyter.org/u/bollwyvl/summary)):

The key resource for the plumbing is in the [Integrating your objects with IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#MyObject._repr_mimebundle_) section of the docs.

Here’s an example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs):
        return {
            "text/plain": f"x={self.x}",
            "text/latex": f"$x = {self.x}\\\\y = {self.y}$"
        }

foo = Foo(1, 2)
foo
```

yields:

[image]